# Most Vexing Friend ? Friend-ing a specialized free-function template raises compilation error (when overloading a method)

Tags: c++, templates, friend

### Code

I reduced the problem to this example (pasted as a single block for ease of compilation)

```
/// \brief The free-function template,
/// which is overloading a method with the same name in AbstractA below.
template <class T>
inline const T overloadedMethod(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{
    return T(lhs.value+rhs.value);
}

/// \brief AbstractA class
class AbstractA
{
public:
    AbstractA (int aVal):
      value(aVal)
      {}


      inline const AbstractA overloadedMethod(const AbstractA &rhs) const
      {
          return AbstractA(value+rhs.value);            
      }

protected:
    int value;
};

/// \brief A class, deriving from AbstractA,
/// and friending the free-function template.
class A : public AbstractA
{   
    friend const A overloadedMethod <A>(const A& lhs, const A& rhs);
        /// This one gives me compilation error
    //template<class T> friend const T overloadedMethod(const T& lhs, const T& rhs);
        /// This one would be okay

public:
    A (int aVal):
      AbstractA(aVal)
      {}
};

int main()
{
   A a1(1), a2(2);
   overloadedMethod(a1, a2);

   return 0;
}
```

### Details

Basically, the compilers I tried (VS 2010 and G++ 4.7.2) give me an error on the line

```
friend const A overloadedMethod <A>(const A& lhs, const A& rhs);
```

They seem to think I am declaring a data member named *overloadedMethod*.

The compilation error is not raised if :

- I give the non-specialized version of the free-function template as a friend (commented line of code)
- I remove the member function **overloadedMethod()** from class **AbstractA**

### Questions

I am not able to explain this behavior of the langage, so my questions would be :

- What is the C++ rule that is leading to this error ? (Why would compilers think I am declaring a data member here ?)
- Do you know a rationale behind it ? (I am especially curious to know why it seems to be working if I remove the **overloadedMethod()** from class **AbstractA**. Or is it an UB ?)

Comment: I doubt you can specialize a non-member function template as a `friend` "member".

Comment: @Tony : What would prevent that ? Anyway, as described in the question, the compilers are happy with this specialized non-member friend function template as long as it is not named the same as a method in the parent class.

Comment: @Tony: Non-normative text in `[C++11: 11.3/3]` says "A friend declaration may be the declaration in a template-declaration (Clause 14, 14.5.4)." 14.5.4/1 even goes so far as to explicitly allow this program, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I'm sure this'll be fixed if you make the name a _qualified-id_. The name from the base hides the global name, no?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Might be a stupid question, but how to make that a qualified-id? `const A ::overloadedMethod` seems not to be interpreted as intended.

Comment: `a friend function definition cannot be a specialization of a function type` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/017869c3.aspx ?

Comment: @catscradle We have no definition here, only a declaration.

Comment: Oh, right, nevermind then.

Comment: @DyP: Yeah that doesn't seem to do it either :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the basic premise of your `friend` declaration is sound:

> `[C++11: 14.5.4/1]:` A friend of a class or class template can be a function template or class template, a specialization of a function template or class template, or an ordinary (non-template) function or class. For a friend function declaration that is not a template declaration:
>
> - **if the name of the friend is a qualified or unqualified *template-id*, the friend declaration refers to a specialization of a function template**, otherwise
> - if the name of the friend is a *qualified-id* and a matching non-template function is found in the specified class or namespace, the friend declaration refers to that function, otherwise,
> - if the name of the friend is a *qualified-id* and a matching function template is found in the specified class or namespace, the friend declaration refers to the deduced specialization of that function template (14.8.2.6), otherwise,
> - the name shall be an *unqualified-id* that declares (or redeclares) an ordinary (non-template) function.
>
> *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class T> class task;
> template<class T> task<T>* preempt(task<T>*);
> template<class T> class task {
> friend void next_time();
> friend void process(task<T>*);
> friend task<T>* preempt<T>(task<T>*);
> template<class C> friend int func(C);
> friend class task<int>;
> template<class P> friend class frd;
> };
> ```
>
> *[..] —end example ]*

You can run into problems because the name `overloadedMethod` from the base class *hides* the global one — irrespective of the different argument list, and the fact that the base name does not represent a template:

> `[C++11: 3.4.1/9]:` Name lookup for a name used in the definition of a friend function (11.3) defined inline in the class granting friendship shall proceed as described for lookup in member function definitions. **If the friend function is not defined in the class granting friendship, name lookup in the friend function definition shall proceed as
>   described for lookup in namespace member function definitions.**
>
> `[C++11: 3.4.1/10]:` **In a `friend` declaration naming a member function, a name used in the function declarator and not part of a *template-argument* in the *declarator-id* is first looked up in the scope of the member function’s class** (10.2). If it is not found, or if the name is part of a *template-argument* in the *declarator-id*, the look up is as described for unqualified names in the definition of the class granting friendship.

The "if it is not found" clause can never be triggered in this case.

In GCC 4.8.1 [this results in the following diagnostic](http://ideone.com/k5Ygaq):

> error: field ‘overloadedMethod’ has incomplete type

I'm sure that the specific contents of this diagnostic are slightly erroneous — you've basically confused the heck out of your compiler, by applying the *template-parameter-list* `<A>` to something that it does not believe is a template.

You cannot fix this, [even by qualifying the `friend` declaration](http://ideone.com/bVAZee):

```
friend const A ::overloadedMethod<A>(const A& lhs, const A& rhs);
```

The following does work:

```
friend auto ::overloadedMethod<A>(const A&, const A&) -> const A;
```

But I think that this is actually a compiler bug, based on the above rules.

Comment: But this works: `friend auto ::overloadedMethod<A>(const A&, const A&) -> const A;` (*had a typo before*)

Comment: @DyP: Updated with what I think is the relevant standard passage.

Comment: Why do you think it's a compiler bug? (How do you come to that conclusion using the quoted rules?)

Comment: @DyP The rules say that the lookup shouldn't find the template, yet your code compiles.

Comment: To be honest I'm kind of reaching, here -- the whole thing seems under-specified.

Comment: @DyP: Read the _whole_ answer: the template would be viable, if not for the lookup rules hiding it.

Comment: 3.4.1/9 doesn't apply, we have no definition here. 3.4.1./10 doesn't apply, as we have to find out it's a member function first (and with the qualified-id, we won't find the member function). (The rest of the 14.5.4 bullets don't apply as well, as the first bullet already applies.)

Comment: let's clean up the comments